# Spot div on same position

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show hide image using javascript. Code works fine but image displays on different location. Now i want to show and hide the images on same spot.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showImage()
    {

        if(document.getElementById('check').checked==true)
        {
            document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = 'visible'; 
            document.getElementById("images").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('check').checked==false)
        {
            document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            document.getElementById("images").style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        }

    }
</script>
<body onload="showImage()">
    <font align="left">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="showImage()" />
    Show Image

    <div class="checkboxes" id = "image" >
        <img  class = "jive-image" height="125" src ="Tulips.jpg ">
    </div>
    <div id="images">
        <img class = "jive-image" height="125" src="Desert.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

How it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `display` style you can remove the image from the page and not just hide it like `visibility`. This will mean the bottom image is pushed up as the first isn't taking up space any more. Set `element.style.display` to `'block'` to show the element and `'none'` to hide it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guMYw/)

```
function showImage() {
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("images").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (document.getElementById('check').checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("images").style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `visibility`. CSS's `visibility` style doesn't affect the page flow. It's as if you were setting the `opacity` to 0. Instead, you may want to use `display`.

```
function showImage() {
    if(document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementById("images").style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("image").style.display = 'none'; 
        document.getElementById("images").style.display = 'block'; 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead setting visibility, set display to either none or block.